# Which module contains TODO List?

Tags: tasks, opp-lineitemschedule

it was evident that we can add Tasks for opportunity, contact ,as well as account . 
Could as add TO-DO List to enhance the granularity of tasks , A Daily TO-DO List ?

Does SalesForce contains this feature or an alternative of this feature ? 
Indeed, I found [this Plugin which is called My task List](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5KJuEAN) . However ,it seems that it converts a list of tasks to TODO List without minimizes the Granularity of Tasks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could write a SOQL query that uses a GroupBy clause to sort Tasks both by their "related to" and their "due date". I think this would create the kind of granularity that you're looking for. I'm confident this type of query could be incorporated into a VF page controller or some other type of application.